# Visual C++ debugging in .NET 2003

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2003

I am trying to debug a large system and the watch lists I add make no sense (to me). I can't find anywhere where the values are displayed. For example, I have an 2D array with a list of doubles, and when tracing through the 2D array, the values are shown through each loop, 1,2,3,4,5,etc... However, one I get to say 9, instead of going to 10, I get 0x00000a  and have no idea what this value is unless I count in my head or with the loop. So short of counting 6000 loop iterations, what number is represented as: 0x00000695 or how can I just get the debugger to show the actual number and not some reference of it? 0x0000014 seems to be 20, and I don't know how I would effectively debug using this watch. Does anyone know how to stop this weird numeric representation? I just want to see the values of the 2D array as I go through the break points.

Comment: What's the *dimensions* of this 2d array? Maybe it only have ten entries (0 to 9)?

Comment: In watch window, right-click + toggle "display values as hexadecimal" to OFF. (sry, can't remember the exact setting name, but its there).

Comment: My word....that was it WhozCraig. I can't believe my Google searching didn't turn that up...Thanks so much! if you post the answer I will accept it =D

Answer (score 0):

In watch window, right-click + toggle "display values as hexadecimal" to OFF. (sry, can't remember the exact setting name, but its there). –  WhozCraig